# how to get web api address that an app calls

Tags: android

I've installed an app from Google Play Store. I want to get the web api adress which the app calls. Is there any way to get that api adress and connect directly from my web browser?

Comment: try to decode your apk and see files in which they are using api... but its very hard... some times

Comment: There are apps you can install that monitor the device network traffic.  Search for them on the play store.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to monitor the network.